# Analytical Solution of Fick's 2nd law , what is C(x, t) = X(x) * T(t)

Tags: physics

Analytical Solution of Fick's 2nd law

[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nu21.jpg)

[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GjYj.jpg)

I just want to know what is C(x,t) = X(x) * T(t)

Please if any one knows pls tell me

Comment: It's called [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations). The authors _assumed_ that $C(x,t)$ was the _product_ of two functions $X$ and $T$, with each function depending on only _one_ of the independent variables i.e $X$ is only dependent on $x$ ($X = X(x)$) and $T$ is only dependent on $t$ ($T = T(t)$).

Comment: @Mattos Thanks, Buddy Thanks a lot, you are Lifesaver Man how do I accept your answer

Comment: You can't, it's only a comment. As long as you understand the content though, I'm happy.